# JMeter Concurrent APIs Parallel Controller

Tags: groovy, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I've been working on trying to make a script that is seeing how the performance of the web application is when multiple APIs/Ajaxs from databases are called concurrently. This is my current approach below.

A few things I noticed when using the parallel controller was that when I use "summary report" I notice that it wasn't taking the total response time, but moreso just the highest one in the concurrent API requests.

I was wondering if there is a workaround for this and how can I create something to show both the total response time of 1 iteration and also the total response times of the APIs concurrently just by themselves?

Any help on using AJAX requests would be great help too, not sure if I am missing things that should be considered/added. (I have not added any assertions, pre/post processors, etc just yet as this is just getting the structure setup first but let me know.)

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see a lot of sense in your requirement, given that:

- requests are executed in parallel
- Parallel Controller execution time is the longest request execution time

I fail to see why would you need the sum of all AJAX requests response times.

Whatever, if you **really** need this you can extract it using i.e. [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler), if you put it after the Parallel Controller and use the following code:

```
def totalTime = 0
ctx.getPreviousResult().getSubResults().reverseEach {
    totalTime += it.getTime()
}
```

then `totalTime` object will contain Parallel Controller's children cumulative elapsed time:

[image]

See [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter.

The value can be stored into a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) so you can add it to the .jtl results file via [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property, [plot custom over time chart](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#customs_graphs), etc.